# NSPredicate for one - to - one relashionships

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have two entities one called `Game` (which has a boolean attribute called `synchronized`)  and one called `Coupon` (witch has a boolean attribute called `won`)
`Game` and `Coupon` are connected via a one-to-one relationship called `hasCoupon`.

I want to fetch all Games which have `synchronized = false` and `won = true`.

Comment: Show us what you'd tried before.. You don't even say which language you're coding in..

Comment: have you seen the tags ? I tried this SPredicate(format: "syncronized = FALSE and SUBQUERY(coupon, $c, $c.won = FALSE).@count = 0") but it didn`t work

Comment: SUBQUERY is only used with to-many relationships (and only if there is no simpler solution – in the answer to your previous question it is actually a workaround for the problem that "NOT ANY" in a Core Data predicate does not work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSPredicate(format: "synchronized = false && hasCoupon.won = true")
```